# Custom actions in a Sharepoint Online (BPOS) workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, custom-action

Just a simple question:

Does anyone know if it's possible to create custom actions for a workflow in Sharepoint Online (BPOS). So **NOT** Office 365... If possible, are there tutorials you know of how to create them?

I've searched this in google, but I could only find info and tutorials for Office 365.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge as those would have to be deployed as features so they'd be available in SPD.  Users don't have that ability to deploy features in BPOS.

Comment: You can however with BPOS-D, which is a dedicated service available for larger customers.

Comment: I allready thought this wouldn't be possible, but maybe you guys would know another solution. And I'm not using a dedicated server. I'll have to search another solution then... Thanks anyways guys